# How to argue in ruby with a hash as parameter

Tags: ruby, hash, parameters

```
class Product < SimpleStore

@@Product = []
@@uniqueid = []

attr_reader :title 
attr_reader :price
attr_reader :manufacturer
attr_reader :manufacturer_code
attr_reader :barcode
attr_reader :hash
attr_reader :code 
attr_writer :price
attr_writer :manufacturer_code
attr_writer :code


def initialize (hsh = {'title' =>nil, 'price' =>0, 'manufacturer_code' =>0, 'barcode' =>nil, 'product_code' =>0})
    @@Product << self
    @title = hsh['title']
    @price = hsh['price']
    @manufacturer_code = hsh['manufacturer_code'].to_i
    @manufacturer = AUTHORIZED_MANUFACTURERS.index(manufacturer_code)
    @barcode = hsh['barcode']
    @code = "#{PRODUCT_TYPES.index[product_code]}--#{@manufacturer_code}--#{@barcode}"
    @@uniqueid << @code
```

When I try to initialize a new product

```
product1 = Product.new({'title'=>"teste",'price'=>10,'manufacture_code'=>0,'barcode'=>"aaa111",'product_code'=>1})
```

I get `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)`

Answer (score 2):

The argument-passing of the initiailization you show works fine:

```
def foo(hsh={'title'=>"teste",'price'=>10,'manufacture_code'=>0,'barcode'=>"aaa111",'product_code'=>1})
end

foo({'title'=>"teste",'price'=>10,'manufacture_code'=>0,'barcode'=>"aaa111",'product_code'=>1})
# => nil
```

I think the error is coming from this:

```
PRODUCT_TYPES.index[product_code]
```

Notice earlier you call the `index` method like this:

```
AUTHORIZED_MANUFACTURERS.index(manufacturer_code)
```

In one case you are using parenthesis (the correct way). In the other, you use `[]` (not correct).

This is a good example of why it's important to read the error messages closely, and look at the line num it gives you for the origin of the error.